# Exception while connecting to postgress DB in Windows Machine

Tags: java, postgresql, c3p0

Getting the below exception while connecting to postgress DB in Windows Machine. Could somebody please help on this

Using c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar

**Exception :**

> 2018-09-26 15:53:41,841 ERROR,
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run
>   , A RESOURCE POOL IS PERMANENTLY BROKEN!
>   [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@87274ea]
>   (because a series of 20 acquisition attempts failed.) 2018-09-26
>   15:53:41,841 ERROR,
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.unexpectedBreak ,
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@735b478 -- Unexpectedly
>   broken!!!
>
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: Unexpected Break
>   Stack Trace! at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.unexpectedBreak(BasicResourcePool.java:974)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$1000(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1927)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
>   java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the following
>   failure: java.lang.InterruptedException at
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118) at
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77) at
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:74) at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:694)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:146)
>   Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1465)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
>   ... 6 more

```
private static ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
try {
cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass(BSMRCommonConstant.POSTGRES_DRIVER);
cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
cpds.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(true);
cpds.setAcquireRetryAttempts(20);
cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
cpds.setMaxIdleTime(60 * 10);
cpds.setTestConnectionOnCheckout(true);
cpds.setAcquireRetryDelay(3000);            
cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(100);          
} catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
Connection con = null;
cpds.setJdbcUrl(url);
cpds.setPassword(password);
cpds.setUser(userName);
con = cpds.getConnection(userName, password);
```

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to put not the error only, but also the code where the error is thrown

Comment: See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Can you add your code here instead of the errors

Comment: It looks like nothing in the stack trace is your code, maybe this is some configuration error and thus not programming related.

Comment: Hi All, Apologies for inconvenience......Below is the code snippet....Last line while connecting to DB the error is being thrown...

Comment: Code snippet has been added.......

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 0):

The c3po database connection pool cannot create a database connection within the configured timeout period.

This is most likely a configuration error. Have a hard look at the url you tell c3po to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andersen for having a look on this..I am using c3p0 version 0.9.5.2, If i will connect from a sample standalone application then its working fine but where as its not working in my deployed application.I have increased the test connection period to 1000 then also its not working.

Comment: If you are absolutely certain that the configuration is correct as seen from the deployment machine, then you may have a firewall issue.  Can you manually connect to the database port described in the configuration?  (In the old days `telnet machine port` could do this, but telnet is not necessarily available these days)